# Prove that f satisfies Cauchy-Riemann Equations but is not differentiable

Tags: complex-analysis, derivatives, cauchy-riemann-equations

Prove that $f$ defined by $f(z) = \frac{z^5}{|z|^4} | (z\neq 0), f(0)=0$ satisfies the Cauchy-Riemann equations at $z=0$ but is not differentiable there.

So I know that $u_x = v_x$.

Therefore let $u(x,y) = |z|^4 = (x^2+y^2)^2$ and let $v(x,y)=
z^5 = (x+iy)^5$.

These are not equal. Where have I made my mistake?

Thank you for any guidance.

Comment: $u$ should be the real part of $f$ and $v$ the imaginary part of $f$. You chose them quite randomly to be the numerator and the denominator, that's why you get a wrong result.

Comment: Wouldn't $u$ then be denominator $|z|^4$?

Comment: I think you're confused about what "real part" and "imaginary part" means.  It doesn't mean components which are real and components which are not real.  What it means is: $f(z)$ is a complex number, so it splits into a real and imaginary part $f(z) = u(z) + i\cdot v(z)$ where $u$ and $v$ are real valued functions.  $u$ is the real part and $v$ is the imaginary part.

Comment: I think that might be my sticking point. So in this case would would be the real and imaginary?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no reason to take $u(x,y)=\lvert x+yi\rvert^4$ and $v(x,y)=(x+yi)^5$. Note that it is not even true that $v$ is a function from $\mathbb{C}$ into $\mathbb R$.

Note that, if $x\in\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$, then $f(x)=\frac{x^5}{x^4}=x$ and that therefore $u(x,0)=x$ and $v(x,0)=0$. So, $u_x(0,0)=1$ and $v_x(0,0)=0$. On the other hand, $y\in\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}\implies f(yi)=\frac{(yi)^5}{y^4}=yi$ . Therefore, $u(0,y)=0$ and $v(0,y)=y$. So, $u_y(0,0)=0$ and $v_y(0,0)=1$. So, $(0,0)$ is a solution of the Cauchy-Riemann equations.

However, $f$ is *not* differentiable at $0$. The limit$$\lim_{z\to0}\frac{z^5}{z|z|^4}=\lim_{z\to0}\frac{z^2}{\overline z^2}$$does not exist. Just see what happens when $z\in\mathbb R$ and when $z$ s of the form $(1+i)t$, for a real $t$.

Comment: But We can see that $|\dfrac{z^5}{z|z|^4}|$ is equal to $1$. Then why doesnt  limit exist

Comment: What has the fact that we always have $\left|\frac{z^5}{z|z|^4}\right|=1$ to do with the non-existence of the limit?

Comment: I meant that the limit exists and is equal to $1$

Comment: @Upstart So what? We have $\lim_{z\to0}\left|\frac{z^5}{z|z|^4}\right|=1$, yes. Why would that imply that the limit $\lim_{z\to0}\frac{z^5}{z|z|^4}$ exists?

Comment: Cant we say $$\left|\dfrac{f(z)-f(0)}{z-0}-L\right|< \epsilon$$ then $L$ is the limit. Which in this case $L=1$

Comment: What is $\epsilon$?

Comment: Arbitrary positive real number.

Comment: The assertion “$\lim_{z\to0}\frac{f(z)-f(0)}{z-0}=1$” has a meaning. And it has a value; it may be true or false. On the other hand, the assertion “For an arbitrary positive real number $\epsilon$, $\left|\frac{f(z)-f(0)}{z-0}-1\right|<\epsilon$” is meaningless. In particular, it is neither true nor false.